# Not able to convert vertical scrolling example to version 4

Tags: rendering, templating, impresspages

I tried it for a couple of days but I seem to be too stupid to adopt the vertical scrolling website example from the blog here:

http://www.impresspages.org/blog/creating-a-vertical-scrolling-website/

I already get stuck with changing the content rendering and creating a V4-compatible foreach part from the first code block:

```
/* SHOW ALL PAGES IN ONE */ 
if ($site->managementState() || $site->getCurrentZone()->getName() != 'menu1') {
  echo $site->generateBlock('main');
} else {
  $pages = $site->getZone('menu1')->getElements();
  foreach($pages as $pageKey => $page) {
    echo '<div class="scrollblock">';
    echo '<div id="page_'.$page->getId().'">';
    $publishedRevision = \Ip\Revision::getPublishedRevision('menu1', $page->getId());
    echo \Modules\standard\content_management\Model::generateBlock('main', $publishedRevision['revisionId'], $site->managementState());
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
  }
}
/* EOF SHOW ALL PAGES IN ONE */
```

Can anybody help me with this? 
I am pretty lost compared to Typo3 which I normally use.

Thank you and best regards,

doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
if (ipIsManagementState()) {

    echo ipBlock('main');

} else {
    $pages = ipContent()->getChildren('menu1');
    foreach($pages as $page) {
        $revision = \Ip\Internal\Revision::getPublishedRevision($page->getId());
        $content = \Ip\Internal\Content\Model::generateBlock('main', $revision['revisionId'], 0, 0);

        echo '<div class="scrollblock">';
        echo '<div id="page_'.$page->getId().'">';
        echo $content;
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot - this looks pretty advanced to me and I am glad you posted this. Like this I learn better to undestand the usage of the IP4 principles in daily life :)
I'll try this out tonight!

Comment: That worked and helped me to understand the terminology and principles of IP 4 much better. Thank you for that!